# wpf DelegateCommand return not fire

Tags: wpf, prism, delegatecommand

I'm using Mvvm pattern and in View when the UserControl-Initialized event is binding to InitializedCommand as below.

```
<i:Interaction.Triggers>
    <i:EventTrigger EventName="Initialized">
        <prism:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding Path=InitializedCommand}" />
    </i:EventTrigger>
</i:Interaction.Triggers>
```

and ViewModel as below.

```
public DelegateCommand InitializedCommand
{
    get
    {
       SelectedPopupType = PopupTypes.Downloading;
       IsShowPopup = true;
       return new DelegateCommand(delegate ()
       {
          *** DoSomething...***
       }
    }
}
```

Other events(Loaded,Unloaded..) return parts are working properly but Initialized Command return does not work (***DoSomething*** not called)..

I wonder whats the reason...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the event name clearly says, `Initialized` event will get triggered before your `Triggers` were set via a `AttachedProperty`. Whereas `Loaded` event will work, as it is triggered after all your property values were assigned and loaded. So, this won't work.

[Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.frameworkelement.initialized) says:

> If you do not need to read element properties, intend to reset properties, and do not need any layout information, `Initialized` might be the better event to act upon.
>
> If you need all properties of the element to be available, and you will be setting properties that are likely to reset the layout, `Loaded` might be the better event to act upon.

Also, why do you want to invoke a `ICommand` for a `Initialized` event? Why can't you have a `EventHandler` at your code-behind for this?

Comment: Actualy I'm new in MVVM, and I'm trying to make without the xaml.cs modifying.
So I wanna to modify only View and ViewModel.
And.. I read your comment so you mean... 
Before 'InitializedCommand return part' be activated Initilized event is already triggered.. right?

Comment: MVVM is not about eliminating `xaml.cs` code and it doesn't break the pattern to invoke the `ICommand` from `xaml.cs` of the same view. Coming back to your question, there is no way to handle the `Initialized` event of `FrameworkElement` using an `EventTrigger` that is defined in the XAML of same control.